# Herramienta para buscar una palabra en todo el sitio

Tags: aplicación-web, buscador

Chicos, lo que sucede es que tengo un sitio Web, pero debo abrir pagina por pagina para buscar una frase, el problema es que son más de 200 paginas entonces estoy buscando una herramienta que lo haga, no se si alguno conozca una que me pueda pasar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso al servidor (y por tanto a todos los ficheros del sitio web) puedes probar con [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) o con [VisualStudio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), ambos tienen busquedas en todos los ficheros de una carpeta y sus subcarpetas.

Para hacerlo deberás o bien:

- instalar uno de estos dos programas en el servidor (a priori no te lo recomiendo).

o bien:

- bajar todos los ficheros que componen tu sitio web (o la subcarpeta que sabes que puede tener el texto a buscar)
- Instalar uno de los dos programas en local

En cualquiera de los dos casos, puedes hacer una busqueda del texto que quieras, en todos los ficheros de una carpeta y en sus subcarpetas.

Comment: Sii, en un inicio pensé en hacerlo así, luego me di cuenta que es un CMS poco conocido llamado "Portal", eso complica mucho ya que no se maneja servidor sino un administrador y no tenemos acceso a la BD